# Road bike assembly - required tools

Tags: road-bike, tools

could you please list a COMPLETE list of required tools to assemble a road bike? I purchased a shimano 105 group set and a Chinese carbon road bike frame with a fork. I'd like to put together my first bike and having this list would eliminate a lot of potential frustration.

Optional: toolset suggestions.

**Frame** - http://pages.ebay.com/link/?nav=item.view&alt=web&id=171304286297 
**Group set**
Shimano 105 5800 Groupset 34/50 Chainset & 12/25 Cassette
Shimano 105 CS-5800 Road Bike Cassette - 12-25 / 11 Speed
Shimano Ultegra 6800 Bottom Bracket - Black / English (BSA)
Shimano 105 5800 CNHG600 Road Bike Chain
Shimano 105 BR-5800 Road Bike Brake Callipers - Black - Pair
Shimano 105 FD-5800 Road Bike Front Derailleur - Black - Black / Braze On
Shimano 105 RD-5800 Road Bike Rear Derailleur - Black - Black / Short Cage SS
Shimano 105 ST-5800 Road Bike Gear Levers - Black
Shimano 105 FC-5800 Road Bike Chainset - Black - Black / 172.5mm / 34/50 / 11 Speed

Comment: Check for bike co-ops in your area that would allow you to use their tools. There's a bike co-op in my area that is well stocked. There's a $5/hour fee for using the tools or you can volunteer in the shop and have the fee waived. They have basically every tool you would need to assemble a bike.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've built pretty similar bike recently (5800 groupset, chinese frame), here's the list of tools used:

1. 2-14Nm torque wrench with a set of hex heads. Without it you might crush carbon fiber parts.
2. Hex keys set.
3. Phillips screwdriver. Used only for derailleur adjustment.
4. Bottom bracket tool that came with SM-BB6800. If you didn't get one, make sure you buy compatible model and not Hollowtech II specific, these BB have different tool interface.
5. Cassette lockring tool. Try to get one with either hex key slot or handle.
6. Rotary tool. Because I didn't have anything better to cut cable housing and cables.
7. Adjusting wrench. Used only to hold lockring tool because it didn't have hex key slot.
8. Carbon fibre paste.
9. Hacksaw and 32 tpi blade. You'll have to cut fork steerer and maybe seatpost.
10. Hacksaw guide.
11. Chain tool.
12. Plastic quick release ratchet clamps to hold stuff tightly.

The rest are optional, but nice to have:

1. Bike stand. If you don't have it, there are various ways to fix bike in place, but I just hung it from shelve using a pair of leather belts.
2. Bench vice.

Obviously, the ultimate target is to build the bike, no matter what tools used. I suggest to make a list of what you have to do, choose suitable tool depending on the budget and only then proceed with purchase.

Oh, and you totally won't need these:

1. Bottom bracket pressing tool - BSA BB just srews in.
2. Headset facing and pressing tools - that frame has integrated cups, just drop bearings into cups.
3. Crown race setting tool - tapered fork crown races usually have a cut that allows to put them on with bare hands or some basic tubing (like toilet paper roll).

Comment: As a side note, I've spent about 70$ on tools including torque wrench, the rest just accamulated over the years.

Answer (score 5):

Tools will be dependent on the standards of the bike. A overview would be:

General

- bike stand
- grease
- carbon paste
- torque wrench

Headset

- tools to chase and face head tube
- bearing press
- crown race setting tool
- steerer cutter

Drive Train

- tool to chase and face bb
- bb bearing press or bb spanner
- chain breaker
- cassette tool
- cable cutters
- cable stretchers
- hex wrenches
- torx wrenches
- crankset preload tool
- screwdrivers

Comment: In this case, I'd add a torque wrench since carbon fiber is sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Individually tools are expensive.  And some (very) expensive tools you would only use once or a few times are not worth buying.  Like Park or Pedros and buy a kit.  It seems like a lot but $200 - $400 is a good starter kit.  Then just fill in with specialty tools or pay to have the work done.

Too many people don't use a torque wrench but with nice bikes you need one.
You will see shop people not use them but they know a lot of the torque by hand.

Comment: On a bike build I get all chasing and facing, headset installed, crown race set and steerer cut by my friendly lbs. I install drive train, brakes and set up cockpit only.

Comment: Shop people use torque wrenches on carbon fiber.

Comment: @Batman Not all and that is not the point. Just because you see an experienced person not use a torque wrench does not mean you should not.

Comment: @Blam: perhaps then you should just say "A torque wrench is recommended as carbon fiber can be easily damaged by over-torquing" and be straight to the point.

Comment: @Batman But that is not my point.  It is not about carbon fiber.  If I am responsible builder and I have a torque range then I will use a torque wrench or not if I think I need one to deliver in that range.  You can crush aluminum if you ignore torque.

Answer (score 1):

The COMPLETE set will likely cost more than 3x the cost of your frame and parts. The tool to prepare a bottom bracket is almost 500 bucks all by itself.

So I'm not going to answer "the COMPLETE set", especially because your copy/paste wall of text doesn't indicate all of the exact specifications for all your parts, which is needed to know exactly which tool is needed.

Get one of the bike Park Tool or similar kits, primarily for home maintenance. Then, get the Park Tool blue book, or some other book, to read so you know what you are doing when installing stuff.

Otherwise, take it to the shop for the elements you can't really do for cheap (frame preparation), or see if any LBS has a public shop option, as Kibbee mentioned in the comment.